# Randomize a range of numbers with Azure Functions for Microsoft Flow

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-functions, power-automate

Within Flow and SharePoint, the request would be an Azure Function to **accept the 2 numbers, randomize them, and return one number in between first number and second number.**

The goal would be to write an Azure Function and provide the URI and other info needed. This is the flow, and the HTTP Web Request is the where the Azure Function is called.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new C# Function with HTTP trigger. Replace the code with something like

```cs
using System.Net;

public static HttpResponseMessage Run(HttpRequestMessage req)
{
    var v1 = ParseInt(req, "v1");
    var v2 = ParseInt(req, "v2");

    return !v1.HasValue || !v2.HasValue
        ? req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Params missing")
        : req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new Random().Next(v1.Value, v2.Value));
}

private static int? ParseInt(HttpRequestMessage req, string name)
{
    string s = req.GetQueryNameValuePairs()
        .FirstOrDefault(q => string.Compare(q.Key, name, true) == 0)
        .Value;
    return int.TryParse(s, out int v) ? (int?)v : null;
}
```

then call it by URL

```
https://{yourapp}.azurewebsites.net/api/{yourfunction}?code={code}&v1={min}&v2={max}
```